# How to detect specific pixel shapes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, opencv, image-processing

I want to detect some specific shaped pixels such as I attached. How can I do this?

I just searched for solution, but I get resources for only basic shapes like circle, hexagon etc.

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is no attachment. Pixels are always square or rectangular. Do you mean clusters of pixels?

Comment: I fixed it, it just a example for. Pixels that represents specifically in a one shape, I mean.

Comment: Though you don't give enough explanations, I guess that this can be addressed as an OCR case.

Comment: so you want to find occurrences with the exact same shape and color?
can you provide the two images as pngs or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use cross correlation [scipy.signal.correlate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.correlate.html) to do template matching. e.g. if you have a template (like the llama in this example) and want to find its position in another image (the canvas), you can cross correlate the two images. You will get maxima (can be multiple) where the same template is found. Finding the maxima will tell you the position of your template.

```
import scipy.signal

xcorr = scipy.signal.correlate(canvas, pic)
xmax, ymax = np.where(xcorr == xcorr.max())

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(10, 6))
ax[0].imshow(pic)
ax[1].imshow(canvas)
ax[2].imshow(xcorr)

circle1 = plt.Circle((xmax, ymax), 50, color='r', fill=False)
ax[2].add_patch(circle1)

titles = ['Template', 'Canvas', '2D Cross Correlation']

for a, t in zip(ax, titles):
    a.set_title(t)
```

[image: template matching example]